# Consultar los registros del mes actual con JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta a una tabla que tiene una fecha de reporte en una base de datos oracle, lo que intento hacer es que cuando se ingrese a la página se desplieguen todos los reportes que pertenecen al mes en curso, estuve investigando sobre las funciones permitidas pero ninguna me funciona, alguien podría orientarme sobre como realizarlo? Gracias !!

En mi entidad el capo fecha_reporte es tipo timestamp

y mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TALARMA T WHERE T.FECHA_REPORTE = MONTH(T.FECHA_REPORTE) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY T.FECHA_REPORTE DESC ", nativeQuery = true)
public List<TAlarma> pageableFindByAlarmaActivoDate();
```

Lo malo es que siempre que realizo esa consulta no me retorna nada

Comment: Prueba de esa manera `SELECT * FROM TALARMA T WHERE MONTH(T.FECHA_REPORTE) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: Estás intentando comparar un mes concreto con el CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Obviamente un mes específico no es igual a toda una fecha, por eso no encuentra nada. Prueba lo que te indican arriba :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás haciendo es comparar la **T.FECHA_REPORTE**, lo que tienes que hacer es de ese campo obtener el mes, que se hace de la siguiente manera`MONTH(T.FECHA_REPORTE)` luego lo comparas con el mes actual que te quedaría `MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`, el query completo sería:

```
SELECT * FROM TALARMA T WHERE MONTH(T.FECHA_REPORTE) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

También te aconsejo que tomes en cuenta el año

```
SELECT * FROM TALARMA T WHERE MONTH(T.FECHA_REPORTE) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND YEAR(T.FECHA_REPORTE) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```